# Setting CSS class to angular component issue

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a module which is a table actually.
The table.component.html source code as follow:

```
<table border=1>
  <theader></theader>
</table>
```

And the theader.component.html source code as follow:

```
<thead #theader>
  <tr><td class="alignCenter underlineText">Table Header</td></tr>
</thead>
```

Furthermore, the content of style.css as follows:

```
.alignCenter
{
    text-align: center;
}
.underlineText
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
table
{
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:1660px;
}
```

I don't know why the text "Table Header" does not align center.
However, the underline decoration works.

Even the computed CSS show the text already aligned.
I attached a screen dump for your reference.

This is [my app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhwtfh) in stackblitz.

[image]

Comment: by introducing `theader`, you are breaking the basic semantic structure for a table. This can result in unexpected issues, like the one you are facing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need reset your `theader` component styles.

```
@Component({
  ...
  selector: 'theader',
  styles: [`
   :host {
      width: 100%;
      display: inherit;
   }
 `],
})
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xo5vhq?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable%2Ftheader%2Ftheader.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

You are applying `text-align: center` on `<thead>`. This ensures that the content *inside* `<thead>` is aligned center.

But `<thead>` element is in `<table>` and is not aligned center. You have apply `text-align: center` on the `<thead>`'s parent element which is `<table>`.

Make following change to your CSS and it should work. But remember that this will also align center other children of `<table>`.

```
table
{
    // Other properties.

    text-align: center;
}
```

Live demo on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ce5qe